# react-navigation can't insert value of my axios in the title; "undefined is not an object"

Tags: react-native, axios, react-navigation

I'm trying to put the value got in my axios inside the title of the navigation but I still have the same error message.
this is my code :

```
fetchWeather () {
    axios.get(`http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=${this.state.city}&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=10&APPID=94c6cf0868fa5cb930a5e2d71baf0dbf`)
    .then((response) => {
        this.setState({report: response.data});
    })
}


static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => {
    return {
        title: `Météo de ${this.state.report.city.country}`,
        tabBarIcon: () => {
            return <Image source={require('./images/avatar.png')} style={{width: 20, height: 20}}/>
        }
    }
}
```

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `navigationOptions` is a `static` function, it is attached to the class definition and not the instance. This means that it cannot use `this` to reach data from a specific instance, which is why you're getting `undefined`.

Instead, you could either set the data to somewhere more global, such as a Redux store, and read it from there, or set the data as a parameter to the navigation state using [setParams](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-prop):

```
...
.then(response => this.navigation.setParams({report: response.data});
```

And then in your `navigationOptions`:

```
title: `Météo de ${navigation.state.params.report.city.country}`
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I undestand where was my error but I don't understand where I have to put the setParams, on this page ? Or on the page where I created the navigator ?

Comment: Every screen in the navigation tree has its own params. You can either call `setParams` if you know you're on the screen that needs them, or call `dispatch` with a `setParams` action, in which you can set the key of the screen you want to set the params to. Take a look [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions#SetParams) for more info.